# Maven runtime error for slf4j dependency

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error, slf4j

My pom.xml dependencies look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I am also building the dependencies jar as follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.dstsystems.gig.gploader.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`maven package` creates two jars, one with dependencies and other without dependencies in the target folder. This gives me two possible usages but both give me run time errors as follows:

usage 1:

```
java -cp target/GPLoader-0.1.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:prod/compDSPConfig/ com.dstsystems.gig.gploader.Main -p $appProperties
```

error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.dstsystems.gig.gploader.utils.ApplicationProperties).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

usage 2:

```
java -cp target/GPLoader-0.1.4.jar:prod/compDSPConfig/ com.dstsystems.gig.gploader.Main -p $appProperties
```

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.dstsystems.gig.gploader.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

As you can tell, I am not very proficient with java but need to run this project successfully to use this app for some Python wrapper functionality that handles a file ingestion. Please help!

Comment: For usage 1, did you follow the instructions in the given link for how to configure Log4j? --- For usage 2, is the `slf4j-api` jar file in the `prod/compDSPConfig/` folder?

Comment: For usage 2, the dependencies jar is in that folder, which should have the slf4j class files in it. Not sure what the slf4j-api jar would add. But let me try and get back.

Comment: For usage 2, the dependencies jar is in the same folder `target/`, which should have the slf4j class files in it. Not sure what the slf4j-api jar would add. 
I tried this, and still same error.

Comment: Don't rely on "should have". Verify for yourself. A jar file is a zip file, so open it with a zip file utility of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

use below dependency into you `pom.xml` and update project and run it :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I already have those dependencies, but a different version. I changed the version as you suggested and tried, but still the same errors.

Comment: try to delete `.m2` folder and then update your maven project and run it.